# For which $\alpha>0$ is the sequence $(n^\alpha\mathbb{X}_{B(0,1/n)})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converge 1) weakly, 2) strongly in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Tags: real-analysis

For which $\alpha>0$ is the sequence $(n^\alpha\mathbb{X}_{B(0,1/n)})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converge 1) weakly, 2) strongly in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

I was told to use Riesz Representation and Holder's inequality but did not see how that can be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the pointwise limit is $0$ so the only limit in either sense is has to be the zero function.

Let $f_n=n^{\alpha}I_{B(0,\frac 1 n)}$. Then $\int |f_n|^{p}=n^{p\alpha}\frac c {n^{d}}$ where  $c$ is the measure of the unit ball. Hence $L^{p}$ convergence holds iff $p\alpha <d$ or $\alpha <\frac d p$. Weak convergence holds for $\alpha =\frac d p$: for $g \in L^{q}$ where $\frac 1 p +\frac 1 q=1$, $\int n^{\alpha} I_B(0,\frac 1 n) g\leq \|n^{\alpha} I_B(0,\frac 1 n)\|_p\|gI_B(0,\frac 1 n)\|_q \to 0$. I will let you show that  weak convergence does not hold for $\alpha >\frac d p$.